# Data Tables State Reset Using Localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I'm having problems using Data Table's (v1.10.6) save feature.

Using the below parameters, it seems that saving and restoring state functionality works correctly, but after a random amount of time, the state gets overwritten with the default table layout. This problem seems to only occur after making table changes at night, then checking the site in the morning to find everything reset. Data Tables *usually* persists the table layout throughout the day, but there are fringe occurrences where table layout gets reset randomly during the day. Data Tables is the only location local storage is being set.

Ideal behavior is that the state of Data Tables, reordering or adding columns, stays indefinitely persistent as a user changes the table.

```
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration : 0,
    stateSaveCallback: function(settings, data) {
        localStorage.setItem('DataTables_Asset_List', JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataTables_Asset_List'));
    }
```

Plugins used:

- Data Tables Bootstrap
- ColReorder

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you've solved this problem, please add answer. This will help other users.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the **stateDuration** option:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateDuration

If your tables are saving to localStorage, this option defines how long the saved state in localStorage is used, before returning back to the default state. The default value of stateDuration is **7200** (or 2 hours).

For example, if a user goes 2 hours without visiting the page/reloading the table, which simply "refreshes" the countdown timer if you will, then the table will load its default settings. Regardless of what is currently in the localStorage. This explains why changes seem to not persist overnight.

In summary, increase the stateDuration option to increase the persistence duration of your tables.

I hope that helps.